# How to view images store in memory?

Tags: windows, image, memory, memory-management, bitmap

I am wondering if their is any tools to view bitmaps that have been stored into the computers memory?

In my application I store a bitmap into the memory, and I am wondering if their are any tools to access/view the bitmap in the memory?

Comment: What programming language do you use?